# Search a database for a sentence separated by a delimiter in SQL

Tags: sql

I currently have knowledge base articles in a database, and the system separates the keywords relating to the article by a semicolon.

On the front facing form, I have a text box limited to 100 characters. How do I create a SQL query that looks at the words within the text box and starts matching those words to the keywords within the database?

I basically want to create a search a little like Google's.

I am currently using `LIKE '%{token}%'`. However, this is not good enough.

Comment: What you mean by search like google one?

Comment: Tokenization and "like" will be your best friends.  Outside of that, there's really not much else to go off of - you tell us that your current query "isn't good enough", but you don't tell us what that query is.

Comment: You could give us some sample data along with what you are expecting your results to look like with a given input, also what language are you using for your front end?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application layer that in-turn interacts with the database, then you should generate that portion of the query, searching for each word at the beginning, in the middle and at the end of the sentence column of each record, for each word in the search text.

```
(
    sentence LIKE 'token;%' 
OR  sentence like '%;token;%' 
OR  sentence like '%;token'
)
```

E.g.

```
Search text = "search google";

Query:
(
    sentence LIKE 'search;%' 
OR  sentence like '%;search;%' 
OR  sentence like '%;search'
)
AND 
(
    sentence LIKE 'google;%' 
OR  sentence like '%;google;%' 
OR  sentence like '%;google'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I had a similar problem.
I solved it by stored function "split". The function splits the parameter by delimiters and returns a table with one column.

This allows you to join the returned table column with your article keywords.

Here is a bit more generic version of the code

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
  WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
  SELECT 1, 1, dbo.GetNextDelimiter(@s,0)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, dbo.GetNextDelimiter(@s, stop + 1)
  FROM Pieces
  WHERE stop > 0
),
Parts(pn,s,start,[end]) as
(SELECT pn,
  SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN (stop > 0) THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s, start, stop
FROM Pieces)
SELECT pn as PartNumber,s as StringPart,(start - 1) start,([end] - 1) [end] FROM Parts WHERE s != ''
)
```

The delimiter function :

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNextDelimiter](@string nvarchar(max), @startFrom int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @response int

SELECT @response = MIN(delimiterIndex) 
FROM
(SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', @string, @startFrom)
UNION
SELECT CHARINDEX('-', @string, @startFrom)
UNION 
SELECT CHARINDEX('''', @string, @startFrom)) as Delimiters(delimiterIndex) 
WHERE delimiterIndex != 0

IF @response is NULL
    SET @response = 0

RETURN @response

END
```

This would allow you to use not only semicolons, but any type and number of delimiters.

From here it's simple

```
Select * from Articles WHERE Token in Split(@Input)
```